# one generic class for multiple variable types

Tags: c#

I would like to have the following class for multiple types (eg `float`, `double`, `decimal`):

```
internal class Progressing_Average
{
    public Progressing_Average()
    {
        _Count = 0;
        Value = 0;
    }
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    private int _Count { get; set; }
    public void AddValue(double input)
    {
        if (_Count == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("max amount has been reached! use preciseaverage or moving avg instead!");
        }
        _Count++;
        Value += (input - Value) / _Count;
    }
}
```

I tried with `internal class Progressing_Average<T>` but the issue is that i cant perform all nessesary operations on `T`

```
Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
```

Is there a way to do this, does it come with performance implications or should I rather use something in the lines of `Processing_Average_Double`

having one class for each type makes the code quite duplicate and harder to maintain i believe

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/

Comment: Short answer: You need to make 3 different classes. Longer answer: Wait for C#11 and you will be able to use `where T : INumber<T>`

Comment: do I have to name them differently or can I name them in the same way and somehow specify which one I want to use (such as with parameter based function selection) `apply(int input)` vs `apply(double input)`

Comment: @DavidG - no you don't. You can use a single generic class, and use lambdas to fill in the missing numeric operators.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou I know, but it's pretty nasty really. Much simpler, reliable and most importantly, more readable to use 3 classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using Lambdas and Expressions

Here is the example code you asked for

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var avg_float = new Progressing_Average<float>();
        avg_float.AddValue(1f);
        avg_float.AddValue(2f);
        avg_float.AddValue(3f);

        Console.WriteLine($"ave={avg_float.Value:f4}");

        var avg_dec = new Progressing_Average<decimal>();
        avg_dec.AddValue(1m);
        avg_dec.AddValue(2m);
        avg_dec.AddValue(3m);

        Console.WriteLine($"ave={avg_dec.Value:c}");
    }
}
```

with sample output

```
ave=2.0000
ave=$2.00
```

#### Generic Math

Ever since NET 3.5, you can do generic math using Expressions and Lambda functions. There is a bit of setup that is needed, but the example below is fairly straightforward.

Some notes:

- Define generic parameter `T` and restrict it to numeric types. Newer NET implementations have better ways of doing this  but for compatibility, with .NET Framework I use the following `where` constraint in `T`
- Define static methods (actually static anonymous functions) for the required math operations. Some basic ones are `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` and the conversion from `int` to `T` for mixing `_Count`.

  These methods are built using a static constructor for the type and are called once for each different `T` used.
- Replace the math operators with the equivalent functions. Like `a+b` becomes `Add(a,b)`.

#### Class Definition

```
public class Progressing_Average<T> where T: struct, 
      IComparable, 
      IComparable<T>, 
      IConvertible, 
      IEquatable<T>, 
      IFormattable
{
    static Progressing_Average()
    {
        var a = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var b = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var n = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));

        Add = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Add(a, b), a, b).Compile();
        Sub = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Subtract(a, b), a, b).Compile();
        Mul = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Multiply(a, b), a, b).Compile();
        Div = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T, T>>(Expression.Divide(a, b), a, b).Compile();
        FromInt = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, T>>(Expression.Convert(n, typeof(T)), n).Compile();
    }
    static Func<T, T, T> Add { get; }
    static Func<T, T, T> Sub { get; }
    static Func<T, T, T> Mul { get; }
    static Func<T, T, T> Div { get; }
    static Func<int, T> FromInt { get; }

    public Progressing_Average()
    {
        _Count = 0;
        Value = FromInt(0);
    }
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    private int _Count { get; set; }
    public void AddValue(T input)
    {
        if (_Count == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("max amount has been reached! use preciseaverage or moving avg instead!");
        }
        _Count++;
        Value = Add(Value,  Div(Sub(input, Value), FromInt(_Count)));
    }
}
```

---

### Support for User Defined Types

If you relax the constraints a bit, you can even use your own types above.

Define the processing class as

```
public class Progressing_Average<T> where T: struct, 
      IEquatable<T>, 
      IFormattable
```

and a user-defined type, such as

```
public readonly struct Point :
    IEquatable<Point>,
    IFormattable
{
    public Point(float x, float y) : this()
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public float X { get; }
    public float Y { get; }

    public static Point operator +(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);
    public static Point operator -(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(a.X - b.X, a.Y - b.Y);
    public static Point operator *(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(a.X * b.X, a.Y * b.Y);
    public static Point operator /(Point a, Point b)
        => new Point(a.X / b.X, a.Y / b.Y);

    public static implicit operator Point(int x)
        => new Point(x,x);
    public static implicit operator Point(float x)
        => new Point(x,x);
    public static implicit operator Point(decimal x)
        => new Point((float)x,(float)x);
    public static implicit operator Point(double x)
        => new Point((float)x,(float)x);

    #region IFormattable Members
    public string ToString(string formatting, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return $"({X},{Y})";
    }
    public string ToString(string formatting)
        => ToString(formatting, null);
    public override string ToString()
        => ToString("g"); 
    #endregion

    #region IEquatable Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Equality overrides from <see cref="System.Object"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="obj">The object to compare this with</param>
    /// <returns>False if object is a different type, otherwise it calls <code>Equals(Point)</code></returns>
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Point item && Equals(item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks for equality among <see cref="Point"/> classes
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>True if equal</returns>
    public bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return X.Equals(other.X)
            && Y.Equals(other.Y);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the hash code for the <see cref="Point"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The int hash value</returns>
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hc = -1817952719;
            hc = (-1521134295) * hc + X.GetHashCode();
            hc = (-1521134295) * hc + Y.GetHashCode();
            return hc;
        }
    }
    public static bool operator ==(Point target, Point other) { return target.Equals(other); }
    public static bool operator !=(Point target, Point other) { return !target.Equals(other); }

    #endregion

}
```

Now watch as you can use the above `struct` to get averages

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var avg_vec = new Progressing_Average<Point>();
        avg_vec.AddValue(new Point(1, 2));
        avg_vec.AddValue(new Point(2, 3));
        avg_vec.AddValue(new Point(3, 4));
        Console.WriteLine($"ave={avg_vec.Value}");
    }
}
```

with output

```
ave=(2,3)
```

There is some skullduggery going on here, because behind the scenes the expression `Expression.Convert()` automatically calls any `implicit operator` for conversions, as well as any user defined arithmetic operators such as `operator + (a,b)`.

Comment: See edits, as I added support for user-defined types.

Answer (score 2):

In .NET 7, you'll be able to use number generics (generic math). In .NET 6, this is not possible.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/

In your example, you would use it like this:

```
internal class Progressing_Average<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    public Progressing_Average()
    {
        _Count = 0;
        Value = default;
    }
    public T Value { get; private set; }
    private int _Count { get; set; }
    public void AddValue(T input)
    {
        if (_Count == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("max amount has been reached! use preciseaverage or moving avg instead!");
        }
        _Count++;
        Value += (input - Value) / _Count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Convert.ChangeType`.

Here is an idea you may like to do

```js
internal class Progressing_Average
{
    public Progressing_Average()
    {
        _Count = 0;
        Value = 0;
    }
    public double Value { get; private set; }
    private int _Count { get; set; }
    // now val could be float decimal int etc..
    public void AddValue(object val)
    {
        double input = (double)Convert.ChangeType(val, typeof(double))
        if (_Count == int.MaxValue)
        {
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("max amount has been reached! use preciseaverage or moving avg instead!");
        }
        _Count++;
        Value += (input - Value) / _Count;
    }
}
```